# Can't find Lemma for set equality in stdpp library

Tags: coq

I am using the stdpp library and I want to show the equality of these two sets:

```
{[x0]} ∪ dom X = {[x0]} ∪ dom Y
```

However, I cannot find a lemma in stdpp to reduce the problem to:

```
dom X = dom Y
```

which I then could solve.
Could someone guide me to the missing Lemma?

Comment: Did you try to call the tactic `f_equal`?

Comment: Thanks! That actually solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the tactic f_equal, provided by the comment by
Pierre Castéran.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).